# Choosing Sharepoint save location for an InfoPath form

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, infopath

I have an InfoPath form template hosted as a Sharepoint content type.  I want the user to be able to choose where in the Sharepoint site folder structure the form gets saved when they click submit.  Is this possible, either by rules or custom .NET code?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in code like this:

http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/11400.aspx